# Как соединиться с камерой через JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Как соединиться с камерой через JavaScript и принимать поток информации?

Comment: Смотрите [здесь][1]
[1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/89832/%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8

Comment: Ключевое: `navigator.getUserMedia`. Плохое: поддерживается только в нестабильных ветках. Отвратительное: придется городить костыли из плагина и апплета.

Comment: Пару лет потерпите и потом navigator.getUserMedia :D

Comment: @Zowie добрый день, коллега из прошлого, пара лет прошло, но так все равно нельзя =D